# Google BigQuery SQL: Fill in empty fields according to another column

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table from Google Analytics 4.
Some of the emails are not shows and I can identify that it is the same user according to the same session id.

```
event_date  email                                      event_timestamp          ga_session_id
24/03/2021  null                                 2021-03-24 21:59:00.315935 UTC     1616623136
24/03/2021  null                                 2021-03-24 21:59:04.370934 UTC     1616623136
24/03/2021  null                                 2021-03-24 21:59:09.360001 UTC     1616623136
24/03/2021  null                                 2021-03-24 21:59:09.552935 UTC     1616623136
24/03/2021  8ydpvvdrs4@privaterelay.appleid.com  2021-03-24 21:59:22.563 UTC        1616623136
24/03/2021  8ydpvvdrs4@privaterelay.appleid.com  2021-03-24 21:59:22.800800 UTC     1616623136
24/03/2021  null                                 2021-03-24 21:59:24.298 UTC        1616623136
24/03/2021  null                                 2021-03-24 21:59:24.299001 UTC     1616623136
24/03/2021  null                                 2021-03-24 21:59:24.535800 UTC     1616623136
24/03/2021  null                                 2021-03-24 21:59:24.536801 UTC     1616623136
24/03/2021  null                                 2021-03-24 21:59:24.834002 UTC     1616623136
24/03/2021  null                                 2021-03-24 21:59:25.071802 UTC     1616623136
24/03/2021  8ydpvvdrs4@privaterelay.appleid.com  2021-03-24 21:59:27.550003 UTC     1616623136
24/03/2021  null                                 2021-03-24 21:59:27.566 UTC        1616623136
24/03/2021  null                                 2021-03-24 21:59:27.567001 UTC     1616623136
24/03/2021  null                                 2021-03-24 21:59:27.614002 UTC     1616623136
24/03/2021  8ydpvvdrs4@privaterelay.appleid.com  2021-03-24 21:59:27.787803 UTC     1616623136
24/03/2021  null                                 2021-03-24 21:59:27.803800 UTC     1616623136
24/03/2021  null                                 2021-03-24 21:59:27.804801 UTC     1616623136
24/03/2021  null                                 2021-03-24 21:59:27.851802 UTC     1616623136
24/03/2021  8ydpvvdrs4@privaterelay.appleid.com  2021-03-24 21:59:34.516003 UTC     1616623136
```

I need to fill all empty email row by session_id
I try to use "lead" or "lag" functions but in result I get only several fills:

```
SELECT event_date,
email,
Lead(email) over (partition by ga_session_id order by event_timestamp ) as ld,
Lag(email) over (partition by ga_session_id order by event_timestamp ) as lg,
event_timestamp,,
ga_session_id
from 'project.dataset.table'
```

What is the correct way to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window functions, but `max()` is most appropriate:

```
select t.*,
       max(email) over (partition by ga_session_id) as imputed_email
from `project.dataset.table` t;
```